# How to create a task (TPL) running a STA thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

Using Thread is pretty straightforward

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(MethodWhichRequiresSTA);
 thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

How to accomplish the same using Tasks in a WPF application? Here is some code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew
  (
    () => 
    {return "some Text";}
  )
   .ContinueWith(r => AddControlsToGrid(r.Result));
```

I'm getting an InvalidOperationException with

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

Comment: For any future visitors who come looking for the real intent of the question: - Using [`StaTaskScheduler`](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/9ae31f531a5f82928134f2ba6f67144e92603e01/csharp/parallel/ParallelExtensionsExtras/TaskSchedulers/StaTaskScheduler.cs) ([guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-5-stataskscheduler/)) as pointed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336082/244353) - DIY version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720496/set-apartmentstate-on-a-task

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx) to get a [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321418.aspx) for the current synchronization context (which is the WPF dispatcher when you're running a WPF application).

Then use the [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321428.aspx) overload that accepts a TaskScheduler:

```
var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task.Factory.StartNew(...)
            .ContinueWith(r => AddControlsToGrid(r.Result), scheduler);
```

Comment: Just to be clear; only the lambda within the ContinueWith method will run with the proper context, not what runs in the main task lambda.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying `TaskScheduler.Current` (from within a WinForms button event handler), couldn't understand why it wasn't working...

Comment: As a point of clarification, there is also an overload for the instance method Task.Start() which takes a TaskScheduler. The details of the question make it clear we're more interested in the continuation case, but the more general question of how to run a Task on an STA thread is not limited to only that case. I wrongly assumed at first I would need continue from an empty "fudge" task in order to run my desired STA task.

Comment: So shouldn't this question's title be edited to better reflect its intention?

Comment: Or broken down into two. "How do i start a task on an STA thread" and "How do i continue a task on an STA thread".

Comment: public static Task<string> ShowOpenFolderPicker()
        {
            var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            var tokensource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(Show,tokensource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None,scheduler);
        }

Comment: where for instance:
        private static String Show()
        {
            var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            dialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return dialog.SelectedPath;
            }
            return null;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher.Invoke could be a solution. e.g.

```
    private async Task<bool> MyActionAsync()
    {
        // await for something, then return true or false
    }
    private void StaContinuation(Task<bool> t)
    {
        myCheckBox.IsChecked = t.Result;
    }
    private void MyCaller()
    {
        MyActionAsync().ContinueWith((t) => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => StaContinuation(t)));
    }
```

Comment: The `ContinueWith` and the `Dispatcher` are considered old-school approaches after the advent of async/await. I would avoid using them for new development (in general).