# "The calling thread must be STA" workaround

Tags: wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library, dispatcher, sta

I know there are a few answers on this topic on SO, but I can not get any of the solutions working for me. I am trying to open a new window, from an ICommand fired from within a datatemplate. Both of the following give the aforementioned error **when the new window is instantiated** (within "new MessageWindowP"):

**Using TPL/FromCurrentSynchronizationContext** *Update: works*

```
public class ChatUserCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object sender)
    {
        if (sender is UserC)
        {
            var user = (UserC)sender;
            var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();                  
            Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>(CreateMessageWindow), user,CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None,scheduler);         
        }
    }

    private void CreateMessageWindow(object o)
    {
        var user = (UserC)o;
        var messageP = new MessageWindowP();
        messageP.ViewModel.Participants.Add(user);
        messageP.View.Show();
    }
}
```

**Using ThreadStart:** *Update: not recommended, see Jon's answer*

```
public class ChatUserCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object sender)
    {
        if (sender is UserC)
        {
            var user = (UserC)sender;

            var t = new ParameterizedThreadStart(CreateMessageWindow);
            var thread = new Thread(t);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start(sender);           
        }
    }

    private void CreateMessageWindow(object o)
    {
        var user = (UserC)o;
        var messageP = new MessageWindowP();
        messageP.ViewModel.Participants.Add(user);
        messageP.View.Show();
    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT. Based on the responses so far, I'd like to point out that I have also tried BeginInvoke on the current dispatcher, as well as executing the code in the original method (that's how the code started). See below:

**BeginInvoke** *Update: not recommended see Jon's answer*

```
public class ChatUserCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object sender)
    {
        if (sender is UserC)
        {
            var user = (UserC)sender;
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<object>(CreateMessageWindow), sender);       
        }
    }

    private void CreateMessageWindow(object o)
    {
        var user = (UserC)o;
        var messageP = new MessageWindowP();
        messageP.ViewModel.Participants.Add(user);
        messageP.View.Show();
    }
}
```

**In same thread** *Update: works if you are on UI thread already*

```
public class ChatUserCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object sender)
    {
        if (sender is UserC)
        {
            var user = (UserC)sender;
            var messageP = new MessageWindowP();
            messageP.ViewModel.Participants.Add(user);
            messageP.View.Show();    
        }
    }

}
```

**BeginInvoke, using reference to dispatcher of first/main window** *Update: works*

```
 public void Execute(object sender)
   {
       if (sender is UserC)
       {
            var user = (UserC)sender;
                    GeneralManager.MainDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                               DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                               new Action(() => this.CreateMessageWindow(user)));      
        }
    }
```

where GeneralManager.MainDispatcher is a reference to the Dispatcher of the first window I create:

```
     [somewhere far far away]
        mainP = new MainP();
        MainDispatcher = mainP.View.Dispatcher;
```

I'm at a loss.

Comment: And what was the problem with calling in the same thread and `BeginInvoke`? In which thread does your `Execute` run?

Comment: You cannot use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` like you do here. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Guys. Still no luck... :( see update again.

Comment: Could you post short, but complete code that we could use to reproduce your issue?

Comment: OK svick. I will try to rip the code out of the codebase and create a minimum reproducible project.

Comment: OMG. Sorry for wasting your time guys. Turns out that all of these options work fine. It just happened to be that a window was also being instantiated from another location that was not UI safe. I couldn't tell because the thread I was watching in the debugger and the parallel one were racing in perfect synchronization!! Will upvote you all and hopefully this is still of some use for people who want to see the different dispatcher options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The calling thread must not *only* be STA, but it must also have a message loop. There's only one thread in your application that already has a message loop, and that's your main thread. So you should use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to open your window from your main thread.

E.g. if you have a reference to your main application window (`MainWindow`), you can do

```
MainWindow.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
    new Action(() => this.CreateMessageWindow(user)));
```

**Update:**  **Be careful:** you *cannot* blindly call `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` because it doesn't do what you think it does. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) says that `CurrentDispatcher`:

> Gets the Dispatcher for the thread currently executing and creates a
>   new Dispatcher if one is not already associated with the thread.

That's why you *must* use the `Dispatcher` associated with an already-existing UI control (like your main window as in the example above).

Comment: Any other ideas Jon? I've tried using the Dispatcher of my main window.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to create a window from a background thread. You cannot do it due to a variety of reasons. Typically you need to create the window in the main application thread.

For your case, a simple idea would be just do it immediately (just call `CreateMessageWindow` inside `Execute`) instead of allocating a `Task`, because your command will definitely fire from the main (UI) thread. If you are unsure about the thread where your `Execute` runs, you can marshal it to the UI thread using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`.

There are really few cases when you would want your new window to run in a non-main thread. If this is really really needed in your case, you should add `Dispatcher.Run();` after `messageP.View.Show();` (using the second variant of the code). This starts the message loop in the new thread.

You shouldn't try to run window in TPL's thread, because these threads are typically threadpool threads, and therefore out of your control. For example, you cannot ensure they are STA (typically, they are MTA).

Edit:
from the error in your updated code, it's clear that the `Execute` runs in some non-UI thread. Try using `Application.Current.Dispatcher` instead of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. (`CurrentDispatcher` means the dispatcher of the current thread, which may be wrong if the current thread is not the main one.)

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your help. Everything you say makes sense, but I only resorted to those techniques because running the code inside Execute caused the same error. See updated question for more things I've tried.

Answer (score 5):

With TPL you can use the [StaTaskScheduler from the TPL Extras](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-5-stataskscheduler/)

It will run tasks on STA threads.

Only used it for COM. Never tried to run several UI threads.