# Are IShellLinkW COM interfaces thread safe?

Tags: c#, com, pinvoke, windows-shell

I am making a number of calls to IShellLinkW.GetPath(...) using PInvoke from C#. I would like to have these being executed concurrently on multiple async Tasks.

Are these calls thread safe? Can I do this?

**Update:**

What I am doing is resolving shortcuts as part of a larger task. Below is the code:

```
    const uint STGM_READ = 0;

    public static string ResolveShortcut(string filename)
    {
        ShellLink link = new ShellLink();
        ((IPersistFile)link).Load(filename, STGM_READ);
        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(260);
        WIN32_FIND_DATAW data = new WIN32_FIND_DATAW();
        IShellLinkW linkW = link as IShellLinkW;
        linkW.GetPath(buff, buff.Capacity, out data, SLGP_FLAGS.SLGP_UNCPRIORITY);
        return buff.ToString();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    struct WIN32_FIND_DATAW
    {
        public uint dwFileAttributes;
        public long ftCreationTime;
        public long ftLastAccessTime;
        public long ftLastWriteTime;
        public uint nFileSizeHigh;
        public uint nFileSizeLow;
        public uint dwReserved0;
        public uint dwReserved1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string cFileName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
        public string cAlternateFileName;
    }

    [ComImport(), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
                  Guid("000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    {
        /// <summary>Retrieves the path and file name of a Shell link object</summary>
        void GetPath([Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszFile, int cchMaxPath, out WIN32_FIND_DATAW pfd, SLGP_FLAGS fFlags);
        /// <summary>Retrieves the list of item identifiers for a Shell link object</summary>
        void GetIDList(out IntPtr ppidl);
        /// <summary>Sets the pointer to an item identifier list (PIDL) for a Shell link object.</summary>
        void SetIDList(IntPtr pidl);
        /// <summary>Retrieves the description string for a Shell link object</summary>
        void GetDescription([Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszName, int cchMaxName);
        /// <summary>Sets the description for a Shell link object. The description can be any application-defined string</summary>
        void SetDescription([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName);
        /// <summary>Retrieves the name of the working directory for a Shell link object</summary>
        void GetWorkingDirectory([Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszDir, int cchMaxPath);
        /// <summary>Sets the name of the working directory for a Shell link object</summary>
        void SetWorkingDirectory([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszDir);
        /// <summary>Retrieves the command-line arguments associated with a Shell link object</summary>
        void GetArguments([Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszArgs, int cchMaxPath);
        /// <summary>Sets the command-line arguments for a Shell link object</summary>
        void SetArguments([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszArgs);
        /// <summary>Retrieves the hot key for a Shell link object</summary>
        void GetHotkey(out short pwHotkey);
        /// <summary>Sets a hot key for a Shell link object</summary>
        void SetHotkey(short wHotkey);
        /// <summary>Retrieves the show command for a Shell link object</summary>
        void GetShowCmd(out int piShowCmd);
        /// <summary>Sets the show command for a Shell link object. The show command sets the initial show state of the window.</summary>
        void SetShowCmd(int iShowCmd);
        /// <summary>Retrieves the location (path and index) of the icon for a Shell link object</summary>
        void GetIconLocation([Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pszIconPath,
            int cchIconPath, out int piIcon);
        /// <summary>Sets the location (path and index) of the icon for a Shell link object</summary>
        void SetIconLocation([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszIconPath, int iIcon);
        /// <summary>Sets the relative path to the Shell link object</summary>
        void SetRelativePath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPathRel, int dwReserved);
        /// <summary>Attempts to find the target of a Shell link, even if it has been moved or renamed</summary>
        void Resolve(IntPtr hwnd, SLR_FLAGS fFlags);
        /// <summary>Sets the path and file name of a Shell link object</summary>
        void SetPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFile);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("0000010b-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IPersistFile : IPersist
    {
        new void GetClassID(out Guid pClassID);
        [PreserveSig]
        int IsDirty();

        [PreserveSig]
        void Load([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFileName, uint dwMode);

        [PreserveSig]
        void Save([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFileName,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fRemember);

        [PreserveSig]
        void SaveCompleted([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFileName);

        [PreserveSig]
        void GetCurFile([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ppszFileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look for yourself, COM servers register their threading requirements in the registry.  IShellLinkW is implemented by the ShellLink coclass which has CLSID 00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046.

Start Regedit.exe and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InProcServer32.  You'll see:

```
  ThreadingModel     REG_SZ    Both
```

"Both" means that you can use the interfaces implemented by ShellLinkW from a thread in the MTA as well.

So yes, it is okay.

Comment: I see the entry in the registry. However, the IShellLinkW I have declared has the CLSID of 000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 and I do not find an entry for this in the registry. When I tried using the CLSID you noted, I do not get the objects (they come back null). I updated my question with source code.

Comment: No, that's the IID, the interface ID for IShellLinkW.  Not the same thing as the CLSID for ShellLink, the class ID.  Don't just arbitrarily change [Guid] attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The windows shell does not support MTA, so you should only call shell interfaces in the thread the shell object is created in (no thread safety), and the thread must be initialized as STA.
If you use the .Net Parallel Patterns Library , see [How to create a task (TPL) running a STA thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971686/how-to-create-a-task-tpl-running-a-sta-thread)