# How to create reportviewer with an asynchronous Task

Tags: c#, task

My function has three parts.

Part one Parameter Popup

Part two Executes the code in a new thread with ApartmentState.STA turned on.

Part three - Show ReportViewer

I am currently receiving this error `the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

```
public async void AnticipatedEntriesReport(bool fund)
{
    var anticipatedReport = new AnticipatedReport(fund);
    ReportPreviewForm report = new ReportPreviewForm();
    anticipatedReport.InitializeParameters();
    if (anticipatedReport.GetParameters() != null)
    {
        await RunAsyncTask(
            () =>
            {
                report = anticipatedReport.GenerateReport(SelectedLoans);
            });

        report.Show();
    }
}
```

My code breaks at report.Show().

anticipatedReport.GenerateReport returns a ReportPreviewForm.

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong? I think it's based on where I created the object.

```
public async Task RunAsyncTask(System.Action action)
{       
    try
    {
        await ThreadManager.StartSTATask(action);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {           

    }        
}

public static Task StartSTATask(System.Action func)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            func();
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tcs.SetException(e);
        }
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just return the report as the task's result?

Comment: What is `RunAsyncTask`?

Comment: @StephenCleary Hi I updated it to include RunAsyncTask method

Comment: @Master: Please reduce to a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can run.

Comment: @StephenCleary Reduced it as much as I can. ReportPrewviewForm is a new window with ReportViewer within it.

Comment: @Master: If it's truly a minimal example, then please post all the code so that others can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the report inside the task and return it to task's parent:

```
public async Task AnticipatedEntriesReport(bool fund)
{
    var anticipatedReport = new AnticipatedReport(fund);
    ReportPreviewForm report = null;
    anticipatedReport.InitializeParameters();
    if (anticipatedReport.GetParameters() != null)
    {
        // Generate the report inside the task and return it.
        report = await RunAsyncTask(
            () =>
            {
                var result = anticipatedReport.GenerateReport(SelectedLoans);
                return result;
            });
    }
}
```

and in RunAsyncTask:

```
public async Task<TResult> RunAsyncTask<TResult>(Func<TResult> function) 
{ 
    TResult result = default(TResult);
    UpdateBusyUi(true); 
    try 
    { 
        result = await ThreadManager.StartSTATask(function); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        SendException(ex); 
        LoadSucceed = false; 
        Events.PublishOnUIThread(new BackgroundCompletedEvent { Header = BackgroundCompletedEvent.EntityActions.Error, Error = true }); 
    } 
    UpdateBusyUi(false); 
    return result;
}
```

The StartSTATask:

```
Task<TResult> StartSTATask<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<TResult> source = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                source.SetResult(function());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                source.SetException(ex);
            }
        });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    return source.Task;
}
```

Comment: Same error here "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." and this time it doens't hit report.show()

Comment: Why are you running the method with `ApartmentState.STA`?

Comment: Because it's a reusable method and if I want to update certain items in the UI, ApartmentState.STA will allow me.....

Comment: How about this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971686/how-to-create-a-task-tpl-running-a-sta-thread

I fixed the answer

Comment: I've added `ConfigureAwait(false)`. How about now?

Comment: Error with ConfigureAwait, same one as earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110435/discussion-between-shlatchz-and-master).

Comment: I just tried this, RunAsyncTask - TResult could not be found, also cannot convert source type `TResult` to the target type 'object'

Comment: What do you mean by "TResult could not be found"?
Are you missing a reference? It should be in `using System.Threading.Tasks;` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: errm, yeah. Try switching `object result = null;` to `TResult result = null;`.

Comment: I made changes and checked them on my computer. Should work now.

Comment: @Master Could you please mark this answer as the correct one, if it helped you solve your problem? Thanks.